# How to return to previous fragment by pressing back?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack

I'm working with a Navigation Drawer navigating to many different fragments. In a few occasions, some fragments are placed over other fragments. However, when I press the back button to bring me to the previous fragment, it brings be back to the home fragment.

**MapFragment.java**

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.navHostFragment, new ImgMapFragment()).addToBackStack(null);
                fr.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fr.addToBackStack(null);
                fr.commit();
```

How do I make it so that when I open **ImgMapFragment**, I can return to the previous fragment I was in instead of the **HomeFragment**

Comment: If you can handle it, you should use Navigation component for that.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: If you use `addToBackStack(null)` ***once***, it should be as simple as `onBackPressed` handling it correctly

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeah, I only have it there once. I'm not sure whats up with it. It just sends me back to the home fragment instead of the Map Fragment for some reason?

Comment: @MuratÇakır yeah im using navigation. But I don't understand when I go from HomeFragment->MapFragment->ImgMapFragment and press the back button, why does it go imgMapFragment->HomeFragment, instead of imgMapFragment->MapFragment?

Comment: You have it there twice in your sample :P

Comment: If you are using Navigation Component, then why do you have ANY fragment transactions at all?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i don't know. Dude, i'm just trying to get it to return to a previous fragment

Comment: Any luck so far?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` methods (there are several to choose from)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidProButNo is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Due to the inherent complexity of the Navigation component, this question is actually much trickier to answer than it first looks, considering you need an understanding of the Navigation component, how to use it, and what it tries to wrap away from you, and so what you shouldn't be trying to use if you are already using the Navigation component.

Navigation component internally uses the `FragmentNavigator`, and the `FragmentNavigator` is what executes an Action that is associated with a `destination`'s ID (`R.id.destination[...]`). The `NavHostFragment` hosts this Navigator for you to make the Fragment-based navigation work via the Navigation component's `NavController`.

Therefore, to "navigate back" when one chooses to use the `NavHostFragment`, one needs to use Navigation Component to define all Fragment destinations, the actions that move between said Fragment destinations, and then pop the Backstack that belongs to the NavController (which will internally manage the FragmentManager).

It looks something like this

A `main_activity.xml` layout

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And `navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
                app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationexample.FirstFragment"
        android:label="First Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/first_fragment" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_first_to_second"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationexample.SecondFragment"
        android:label="Second Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/second_fragment" />

</navigation>
```

Then to navigate from one screen to another, you need to do

```
try {
    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_first_to_second);
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

And to return, you have to do

```
try {
    Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackstack();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

And as you are in this case using Navigation component, you shouldn't manually manage FragmentTransactions because it will make the Navigation component's backstack inconsistent.

Theoretically, if you did this correctly, then `onBackPressed` should already be handled by Navigation component correctly, as I believe they register themselves as a `OnBackPressedDispatcher`, and *don't* have to delegate the back event over manually.